# How to installl inflator for reaver in ubuntu

Tags: pentesting

I really like the gui for reaver inflator (you can put your card into monitor mode and start your pentest attacks easily) I have always use it with wifislax, but no idea of how to install it on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have you tried `wifite` instead?